# Request Entity Too Large when transferring data between FormStack and Excel

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

We have a simple automated flow as seen below, where, once a form document is submitted in FormStack, that information gets written into and excel table.
[image]

Users that submit the form can also append a .pdf document to it, so we have a few uriComponentToBinary operations that convert the document for future use. We run into an issue where some submitted documents are considered too large (a particular one was 14 Mb) which results in the following error:

```
{
"statusCode": 502,
"headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "x-ms-datasourceerror": "True",
    "x-ms-request-id": "d437f9e9-a72f-4e30-b6d0-1658d387048d;83b14435-297e-43ed-9f28-85c01cf25ca2;75061535-3db0-49be-9192-64a814932d59;3e0bac7b-b1a5-48d0-8303-d1622bd12989",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
    "x-ms-apihub-obo": "true",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Date": "Thu, 29 Sep 2022 14:46:14 GMT",
    "Content-Length": "669",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Expires": "-1"
},
"body": {
    "error": {
        "code": 502,
        "source": "flow-apim-msmanaged-na-centralus-01.azure-apim.net",
        "clientRequestId": "690b5892-3ee3-44ae-8029-dbbafe164d8d",
        "message": "BadGateway",
        "innerError": {
            "status": 502,
            "message": "Request Entity Too Large\r\nclientRequestId: 690b5892-3ee3-44ae-8029-dbbafe164d8d\r\nserviceRequestId: d437f9e9-a72f-4e30-b6d0-1658d387048d;83b14435-297e-43ed-9f28-85c01cf25ca2;75061535-3db0-49be-9192-64a814932d59;3e0bac7b-b1a5-48d0-8303-d1622bd12989",
            "error": {
                "message": "Request Entity Too Large"
            },
            "source": "excelonline-ncus.azconn-ncus.p.azurewebsites.net"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is this issue fixable, or is there a limit for such operations in PowerAutomate?

Thank you!

Comment: So are you saying that you pump the 14mb file contents into the Excel workbook, is that right?

Comment: Yes, normally the files don't exceed 1 Mb and the process is working well, we have trouble with larger files though

Comment: I think there’s a limit of 5mb so you’re kinda stuck. Why don’t you upload the file to somewhere like OneDrive or SharePoint and then provide the link in the excel workbook instead of the attachment directly? Is that an option?